# Before insert into SQL Server, join VB.NET DataTable with SQL Server table and then insert result into SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I want to transfer data from a VB.NET datatable into SQL Server.

But before transferring the data into the SQL Server main table, I want to process this data with the existing data in another SQL Server table (like left joins) and then insert that result as the actual data the main SQL Server table.

The VB.NET data table has around 2000 rows.

I thought to do it with 'for loop' each record with insert SQL statement in VB.NET but than has two down side.

1. it inserts records into SQL Server table without required join process and
2. 'For Loop' for 2000+ records is not good on the client application.

To avoid 'for loop', there is an option of `SqlBulkCopy`, but again it inserts VB.NET datatable into SQL Server without the desired data process.

Again explaining requirement: I want to join VB.NET datatable with some table in SQL Server and that result needs to be inserted into the main table of SQL Server.

Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

You can passing a DataTable to SQL-Server as a Table-Valued-Parameter.
Here you can find more information:

https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/passing-table-valued-parameters-from-dotnet-to-sql-server

Comment: This is not specific enough to be an answer. Of course, the question is not specific enough to have been answered in the first place.

Comment: I edited a few things in question and tried best to explain the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What @BennoDual said, but with a bit more detail:

You have a set of data (DataTable) in VB.Net. You want to load data from that dataset into SQL, after modifying it somehow based a second set of data stored in a SQL table. Based on this, presumably:

- You do not want to load the second set of data into VB.Net
- You do not want to alter the first data set as it is stored in VB.Net

One way would be to *temporarily* load the second set of data from SQL into a second set in VB.Net, build a *temporary* third set with the modified version of the data, and load that to SQL. Sounds like too much work to me. A more SQL-centric way would be:

- Create a stored procedure in SQL
- The procedure has a parameter, where the parameter is a Table Value Parameter [TVP]
- (Which requires that you create the TVP before you create the procedure. This, along with how to create stored procedures, is outside the scope of this answer.)
- Call the procedure from VB.Net, passing in the first set of data via the TVP parameter
- Within the procedure you now have the first set of data in the TVP, and the second set of data is readily available in the table
- You can then write an `INSERT... SELECT...` statement that inserts rows into the target table based on a join between the TVP and the second table.